# Why would clicking "View All Site Content" generate an error?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

I have a SharePoint site where clicking "View All Site Content" generates this error:

> The URL '/sites/foo/bar' is invalid.  It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Hm, maybe you can check whether any web part is causing problems.

Just add **?contents=1** at the end of the URL and you will go to the Web Part Maintenance mode for the current page.

It's a long shot, but with SharePoint you never know :)

Comment: View All Site Contents shouldn't run any web parts, so there shouldn't be anything to mess up, I would think.  I will check though.

Answer (score 1):

Could be an issue with an unpublished system masterpage for the site. Try looking at http://[yoursitecollection]/_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx to see if there is an issue.